# Encompass the output of a for loop into a variable in python

Tags: python, json, loops, twilio

I'm trying to define the following for loop as a variable so that it can be sent as a text message using Twilio.  The for loop is parsing some json output.

```
for item in parsed:
    print item['resource']['caseNumber'], \
    item['resource']['subject'], \
    item['resource']['status'], \
    item['resource']['severity']
```

The following code snippet produces output like:

```
123458 Subject Example Status Example 4 (Low) 
123138 Subject Example2 Status Example 3 (Normal) 
145541 Subject Example3 Status Example 2 (High)
```

I'm trying to encompass that entire output into a variable, is that possible?  If not, what's the best way to take the output I've captured from the for loop above and then send it via Twilio with:

```
# Send text messages 
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages.create(to=to,from_=from_,body=body)
```

Comment: I think you should define an object and instantiate them inside of the loop. Then you can use the objects to send your messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could send a list of strings

```
body=[]
for item in parsed:
    body.append(item['resource']['caseNumber'], \
        item['resource']['subject'], \
        item['resource']['status'], \
        item['resource']['severity'] )
```

or you could just send one long string, with newlines appended to the end of each iteration of the for-loop.

```
body=''
for item in parsed:
    body = body + str( item['resource']['caseNumber'], \
        item['resource']['subject'], \
        item['resource']['status'], \
        item['resource']['severity'] + '\n' )
```

Comment: Or even ```body = ' '.join([item['resource']['caseNumber'], item['resource']['subject'], item['resource']['severity']]```.